# Python interpreter completely skips function asking for user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

At first I had `Choice = input("Do you " + colored("run ", 'blue')+"or " + colored("attack? ", 'blue') + "")` and everything worked fine, user could do input and code continued as normal. However, I wanted to change this to a function so I now have

`def func(Choice):
  input("Do you " + colored("run ", 'blue')+"or " + colored("attack? ", 'blue') + "")` and the python interpreter completely skips over the function and doesn't ask for input. I'm relatively new to python so I apologize if I did something stupid but I couldn't find any answers online. The version is 3.5.2 by the way.

Comment: had you tried calling the function?

Comment: Do you ever call the function, or do you just define it?  Also, `Choice` should be the return value of the  function, not a parameter.

Comment: I didn't think I would be able to call it without taking user input first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused.  You need to call the function in order for it to be executed.  When the interpreter encounters the `def` statement it makes a function according to the definition.  It will never be executed unless you call it.  You want something like:

```
def func():
    choice = input("Do you " + colored("run ", 'blue')+"or " + 
       colored("attack? ", 'blue') + "")
    return choice
```

Whenever you want the user's input, you write

```
choice = func()
```

or something similar.  The variable doesn't need to have the same name in both places.